# anuncio admob no fragment android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estou tentando adicionar anúncio banner no meu app pelo Fragment, mas não consegui, não aparece nada. O que posso fazer pra resolver?

fragment_inicio.xml

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="324dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

InicioFragment.java

```
        private AdView mAdView;

public InicioFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);


        mAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

androidManifest

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o admob aparecer no aplicativo, primeiro ele tem que estar publicado na play store, por alguns dias.

O principal problema que identifiquei é que você está usando o mesmo ID no manifest quanto no banner no fragment.

crie as strings dos ads em res/value/strings.xml:

```
<string name="adAPPId">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx</string>
<string name="adUnitId">ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx</string>
```

Repare que o AppId possue o "~" e o adUnitId possue o "/".

Agora no meta-data do seu manifest deixe o campo value como a seguir:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/adAPPId" />
```

E no xml do seu fragment altere:

```
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

para:

```
ads:adUnitId="@string/adUnitId"
```

Para teste é possível de fazer com que ele apareça alterando:

```
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

para:

```
        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        }

        AdRequest adRequest = builder.build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Obs: Talvez o `AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR` não funcione, nesse caso, enquanto estiver correndo o programa pelo android studio, vá até a aba embaixo denominada "Logcat" e procure por Ads, terá alguma mensagem como

> Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("Algum_Valor") to
>   get test ads on this device.

Então copie esse valor que ele fornece e coloque no lugar do `AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR`

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço